# What does the green/amber/red light next to the time remaining in navigation mean?

Tags: google-maps-navigation

I think it's something to do with how fast/slow you're going, but some clarification would be nice.[image]

Comment: +1 Oh how I want to know the answer to this. My *guess* was it was showing the traffic-state of the roads left on your journey (green = clear, red = congested).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Google Maps Navigation also provides Live Traffic Information along your route, updated every few minutes. **A red/amber/green light in the corner shows if there are any traffic problems anticipated along your route.** If there are, you can see where the holdups are and have the option to press to re-route which will find a route avoiding the traffic holdups.

Source: http://mobile.jack-frost.co.uk/google_maps_navigation_review_uk.php
Also: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/android/thread?tid=4f7b34dd18f74b75&hl=en
(Via: [Google Search For "google navigation amber green light"](http://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1&nord=1#sclient=psy&hl=en&nord=1&biw=1086&bih=778&site=webhp&source=hp&q=google%20navigation%20amber%20green%20light&pbx=1&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&fp=d9a610ca327ef5ed&ion=1&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=d9a610ca327ef5ed&ion=1))